# How to solve Jenkins 2.361.4 start with ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy error?

Tags: java, jenkins, upgrade

I upgraded jenkins from 2.263.4 to 2.289.3, upgraded the JDK 11 juste after jenkins upgrade 2.319.3 and then continued the process to 2.361.4 with each intermediary LTS upgrade and upgraded compatible plugin at each intermediary upgrade.

All the process was smooth, but now jenkins 2.361.4 don't start with properly with systemd:

```
systemctl start jenkins
```

The process is up, but UI is stucked on an error page.

```
jenkins  24449     1 16 14:57 ?        00:00:09 /usr/bin/java -Xmx2048m -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=%C/jenkin
```

Here's the detailed output from systemd:

```
 systemctl status -l jenkins
● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: activating (start) since ven. 2024-03-15 11:41:08 CET; 30s ago
 Main PID: 684 (java)
   Status: "Jenkins stopped"
   CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
           └─684 /usr/bin/java -Xmx2048m -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=%C/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080

mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:543)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:175)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1161)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:222)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:121)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:70)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Here's journalctl -xe:

```
[xxxx@xxxxxx ~]# journalctl -xe
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1161)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:222)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:121)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:70)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: 2024-03-15 10:41:12.209+0000 [id=28]        SEVERE        jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFail
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Display URL API (display-url-api 2.3.5)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: - Update required: SSH server (sshd 3.0.3) to be updated to 3.236.ved5e1b_cb_50b_2 or higher
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:994)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:543)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:175)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1161)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:222)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:121)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:70)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
mars 15 11:41:12 xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx jenkins[684]: at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Jenkins UI show only an error page with the following:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.SecurityMapper.realClass(SecurityMapper.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at hudson.util.XStream2$CompatibilityMapper.realClass(XStream2.java:411)
    at hudson.util.xstream.MapperDelegate.realClass(MapperDelegate.java:46)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:125)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:47)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.determineType(RobustReflectionConverter.java:523)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:348)
Caused: jenkins.util.xstream.CriticalXStreamException: 
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
class               : hudson.model.Hudson
required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
path                : /hudson/authorizationStrategy
line number         : 8
version             : not available
-------------------------------
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:383)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:291)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:52)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:136)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1421)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:189)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:160)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1399)
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:196)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:199)
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:179)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3299)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$12.run(Jenkins.java:3401)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1161)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:222)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:121)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:70)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:291)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:49)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1196)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:986)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:264)
```

Current java binary version from JDK is /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.22.0.7-1.el7_9.x86_64/bin/java

How to solve this error and start jenkins properly?

I tried to move all plugins to different directory without success